# NullReferenceException from Exchange.WebServices.Managed.Net5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Triggering mail from ASP.net Core MVC application, using Exchange.WebServices.Managed.Net5(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Exchange.WebServices.Managed.Net5/2.2.0).Intermittently getting the **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**, Sometimes mail gets send even after the exception.
Why this error and how can it be solve?

```
public static void CreateMessage(string username, string To, string Subject, string Msg, string Smtp, int Port, string Password, bool useSsl, string ToCc = "")
       {
           try
           {

               ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

               service.Url = new Uri("https://" + Smtp + "/ews/Exchange.asmx");
               ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
               service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
               service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, Password);


               EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
               message.Subject = Subject;
               message.Body = Msg;
               message.ToRecipients.Add(To);
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ToCc))
                   message.CcRecipients.Add(ToCc);
               message.Save();

               message.SendAndSaveCopy();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw new Exception("Email sending error:" + ex.ToString());
           }
       }
```

Comment: Where is your code? What property or method gives the error? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: Edited query, message.Save() gives error, and yes have debugged the code and the issue occurs intermittently. The object that gives error is never null randomly the object becomes null

Comment: Calling this method results in at least one call to Exchange Web Services (EWS). Have you tried checking the call results?

Comment: You may also try to specify the folder name where to save the item, see `Save(WellKnownFolderName)`.

Comment: I'd be careful using that nuget package they have no public repo (so you can't find the bug or report the issue) and it's not an official Microsoft version.